# groovy sum of array (with string conversion)

Tags: arrays, groovy, sum

I have a JSON response from a REST post. Now I want to get the sum of a field.

```
restResponse*.amount.sum()
```

But the amount field is a string so it just concatenats those strings ...

Is there a way to convert the strings 'on the fly' to float or double for .sum()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :-

```
 //sum in integer
 restResponse*.amount*.toInteger().sum()

 //sum in double
 restResponse*.amount*.toDouble().sum()

 //sum in float
 restResponse*.amount*.toFloat().sum()
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Thx. Since I have decimals i use .toFloat().